# Blazor wasm localization date format incorrect

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am getting wrong dateformat for danish and english-danish culture in Blazor wasm

Console App example

```
CultureInfo ci = new("en-DK");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

var date = new DateOnly(2023, 07, 25);

var rwerwer = date.ToShortDateString();
// da-DK Output: 2023-07-25
// en-DK Output: 25/07/2023
```

Blazor wasm example

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization;

@{
    DateTime qweqw = new DateTime(2023, 07, 25);
}

<p>@qweqw.ToShortDateString()</p> 
@* da-DK Output: 25.07.2023 *@
@* en-DK Output: 25/07/2023 *@
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
var culture = new CultureInfo("da_DK");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization" Version="7.0.10" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What can I do to make my wasmp example app give the same output as the Console app example?

I am expecting Console App and Blazor wasm to give the same date formats with localization

Answer (score 0):

in your Program.cs of your Blazor project:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("da_DK");
```

You have an `_` instead of a `-`

Try to set the CurrentCulture too, I have theses lines in my app, it works well :

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```